# Swashbuckle for Azure Functions: No API definition provided when it runs on Azure

Tags: azure-functions, swagger-ui

I added `Swashbuckle` in my `Azure Function` v3 to generate Swagger documentation. I followed the instruction in this [post](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/csharp/adding-swagger-ui-documentation-to-azure-function-apis/) and locally is working.

[image]

I published from my laptop this function to the Azure Portal in my function. The function is working but there is not Swagger documentation.

[image]

```
{
  "schemaValidationMessages": [
    {
      "level": "error",
      "message": "Can't read from file https://azuks-myfnz-q001.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger/json?code="
    }
  ]
}
```

I checked in the project to verify the generation of the XML. I can see the XML in the project. Also, I tried to change the file property "Copy to Output Directory" (apparently it is not required).

[image]

[image]

I published the Azure Function multiple times in *Debug* or *Release* and only once was working in Debug mode. I tried to **Delete Existing Files** with the same result.

[image]

### Update

I updated `AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle` to the version 3.1.6 and now I have another error on Azure:

> Failed to load API definition.

[image]

I checked in the project `.csproj` and I can see

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I created a test project on [Github](https://github.com/erossini/AzureFunctionsSwashbuckle).

### Update #2

For same reason, the code param can't be the same for `json` and `UI`. If you open your Swagger url with **Get Function url** and copy the url from UI function, it is working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.4.4, that is referenced by your project is an older version of the same lib, which is forked and has version 3.1.6.

As original repo is no longer supported.

Now, only fork => https://github.com/vitalybibikov/azure-functions-extensions-swashbuckle
supports your version of Azure Functions, (which is v3)

So, you need to use only AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle package,

```
   <PackageReference Include="AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle" Version="3.1.6" />
```

and configure it as described in repo.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, when we use sdk `AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle` to integrate swagger fro Azure function, we can do the following steps to include xml

1. Change your functions project's GenerateDocumentationFile option to enable. Please add the following element in `.csproj` file

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

2. Add configration setting this extensions on your functions project's hots.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "Swashbuckle": {
      "XmlPath":  "{your document xml file name}" 
    } 
  }
}
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/azure-functions-extensions-swashbuckle#include-xml-document-file)

[image]