# Swashbuckle for Azure Functions v3: failed to load API definition

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions

I created a simple project where I added the latest version of the extension. I published my code on [Github](https://github.com/erossini/AzureFunctionsSwashbuckle). I use Azure Functions v3. The dependencies are:

- AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle 3.1.6
- AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle 1.4.4
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.3

I followed the steps on theSwashbuckle [page](https://github.com/yuka1984/azure-functions-extensions-swashbuckle). Locally is working. When I publish the function on Azure, I get this error:

[image]

```
{
  "schemaValidationMessages": [
    {
      "level": "error",
      "message": "Can't read from file https://azuks-test-q001.azurewebsites.net/api/swagger/json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Before this, I faced another issue that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734672/swashbuckle-for-azure-functions-no-api-definition-provided-when-it-runs-on-azur). I can't understand what changed.

### Update

For same reason, the code param can't be the same for `json` and `UI`. If you open your Swagger url with **Get Function url** and copy the url from UI function, it is working.

[image]

Comment: I found useful those posts https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/csharp/adding-swagger-ui-documentation-to-azure-function-apis/ https://www.puresourcecode.com/news/adding-swagger-to-web-api-project/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently only fork => https://github.com/vitalybibikov/azure-functions-extensions-swashbuckle

supports your version of Azure Functions, (which is v3)

Comment: I am using this NuGet package. But it does not respect JsonProperty attribute of NewtonSoft.Json. Do you have any idea about that?